# Kafka producer difference between flush and poll

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

We have a Kafka consumer which will read messages and do so stuff and again publish to Kafka topic using below script

producer config :

```
{
  "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
}
```

I haven't configured any other configuration like `queue.buffering.max.messages` `queue.buffering.max.ms` `batch.num.messages`

I am assuming these all will be going to be default values from [configuration](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md)

```
queue.buffering.max.messages : 100000
queue.buffering.max.ms : 0
batch.num.messages : 10000
```

my understanding : When internal queue reaches either of queue.buffering.max.ms or batch.num.messages messages will get published to Kafka in separate thread. in my configuration queue.buffering.max.ms is 0, so every message will be published as soon as when I call produce(). correct me if I am wrong.

My producer snippet:

```
def send(topic, message):
    p.produce(topic, json.dumps(message), callback=delivery_callback(err, msg))
    p.flush()
```

from [this post](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/137#issuecomment-424600189) i understand that using flush after every message, producer is going to be sync producer .  if I use above script it is taking ~ 45ms to publish to Kafka

If I change above snippet to

```
def send(topic, message):
    p.produce(topic, json.dumps(message), callback=delivery_callback(err, msg))
    p.poll(0)
```

Is there any performance will be improved ? Can you clarify my understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The difference between `flush()` and `poll()` is explained in the client's [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html).

For [`flush()`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Producer.flush), it states:

> Wait for all messages in the Producer queue to be delivered. This is a
>   convenience method that calls poll() until len() is zero or the
>   optional timeout elapses.

For [`poll()`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Producer.poll):

> Polls the producer for events and calls the corresponding callbacks
>   (if registered).

Calling `poll()` just after a `send()` does not make the producer synchronous as it's unlikely the message just sent will already have reached the broker and a delivery report was already sent back to the client.

Instead `flush()` will block until the previously sent messages have been delivered (or errored), effectively making the producer synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for info. it really worked for me. time come from 45ms to ~0.2ms

Comment: This post doesn't explain OP's questions about the configuration though. Regarding that here's my understanding: 1.(Have already tested this) You end up running produce past the `queue.buffering.max.messages` limit. You get an exception. 2.(I'm uncertain and this is just my assumption) You end up running produce past `batch.num.messages` this setting. It's possible that messages are delivered even before you flush.

Comment: `flush()` will wait until delivery report is acknowledged which is much longer than `poll(0)` which only tries to get the delivery reports of previous sent messages. If one is interested in details, [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/137) worth a read.